# How to use prototypes in NodeJS MVC - trying to add default value of model variable using a prototype function

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

I am relatively new to Node JS - searched lots of sources, spent more than a day - no luck.

I have a usual NodeJS app using Mongoose model, Routes and Controllers.

Below is my model and how I create new object in Controller.

HOW & WHERE CAN I ASSIGN VALUE OF reservationNumber USING PROTOTYPE FUNCTION?   Assume a guest stays at a resort hotel and is in process of booking a SPA procedure. Resort hotel reservation number (unique to this guest) should be attached to all SPA bookings made.

```
// MODEL TO BOOK SPA PROCEDURE FOR A HOTEL GUEST
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Users_BookingSchema = new Schema({
    bookingname: {type: String, required: true, unique: true, min: 3, max: 100},
    // reservationNumber:  {type: String},      // NEEDS TO BE ASSIGNED USING PROTOTYPE
    starttime: {type: Date, required: true},
    endtime : {type: Date, required: true}
});

Users_BookingSchema
    .virtual('url')
    .get(function () {
  return '/users_booking/'+this._id;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users_Booking', Users_BookingSchema);
```

AND FROM CONTROLLER:

```
// PART OF FUNCTION SAVING HOTEL SPA PROCEDURE BOOKING - create on POST
var sbt = new Users_Booking({ 
  bookingname : req.body.bname,
  starttime : jsDateStart,  // PARSED DATE IS ASSIGNED
  endtime : jsDateEnd   // PARSED DATE IS ASSIGNED
  // could add code below here - but trying to use prototype
});
```

I know that I can add the below code to above extract from the Controller

```
  let resNumb = getReservationNumber();
  reservationNumber: resNumb;
```

but I am trying to learn how i can APPLY PROTOTYPES to achieve this:

I do NOT think that I need to add following function to model file as Users_Booking IS NOT DEFINED

```
Users_Booking.prototype.reservationNumber = function() {
    return "4236";  // ASSUME THIS RETURNS RESERVATION NUMBER UNIQUE  TO GUEST BEFORE MAKING A SPA PROCEDURE BOOKING
}
```

Am I in right direction at all?

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what you're trying to do.  Is the `reservationNumber` a persistent property of the booking, like `bookingname` and `startttime`?  If so, it should probably be part of the `UsersBooking` Schema, like those other properties.  I don't understand why you are wanting to add it to the prototype as a function.  Is it your intention to extend the framework somehow?  Please explain further if you can, a little "why" you want to do this might help.

Comment: Why do you assume that this function should go on the prototype? Of what class? Notice that if you want to invoke it in `var sbt = new Users_Booking({…, reservationNumber: ???()}`, there is no instance yet that you could call a method on. So just make it a static function. Or put it as a method on the controller, not on the model.

Comment: @Matt Morgan  The reservationNumber has nothing to do with the booking as reservationNumber does not change once a guest has checked in to a resort hotel. During his/her stay this guest may make bookings to reserve place in the resort SPA. There may be several SPA bookings. All such bookings must contain the reservationNumber so that hotel management can identify the guest. So it is not what you defined. What I am doing is a learning project. Can you please give any example of assigning model variable in an Node MVC app using prototypes? I am trying to learn use of prototypes in a Node MVC app

Comment: @Bergi What I am doing is a learning project. Can you please give any example of assigning model variable in an Node MVC app using prototypes? I am trying to learn use of prototypes in a Node MVC app. In case of my app during guest's stay at the hotel his reservationNumber does not change. Any actions of this guest (purchases, in-hotel bookings, orders & etc.) should be linked to this reservationNumber. Are prototypes used in similar cases? If not can you please give any (or few) example(s) of using prototypes in Node MVC apps ? Or should I ask another question in this site for this? Thank you

Comment: @Ula No, you cannot and should not use prototype inheritance for the reservation number here. Don't try to learn that. Just make it a normal property like the other ones in your schema.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you so much !    I take your word that I cannot and should not use prototype inheritance in similar cases. If you can't or don't want that is fine. But if you can - could you write an Answer ( not Comment ) elaborating a little more as to why one cannot and should not use prototype inheritance in similar cases ? Then I would up-vote and accept your answer. I am sure that I am not the only one new comer to NodeJS who is trying to learn if they can assign non-changing values to model variables using prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea. With the Users_Booking class created from mongoose, you can now reference Users_Booking with the class functionality of mongoose *(all the methods described in the mongoose docs)* and Object() *(JavaScript base prototype)*. Both are inherited to Users_Booking. Here is some proof:

```
const Users_Booking = mongoose.model('Users_Booking',  Users_Booking_Schema);

console.log(Users_Booking.__proto__); // outputs all of the native mongoose methods
console.log(Object().__proto__.isPrototypeOf(Users_Booking.__proto__.__proto__)); // 'true'
```

If you would like to add alongside all of that a getReservationNumber() function, you definitely could. I would much prefer this:  `const Users_Booking = module.exports = mongoose.model(/* ... */);`. Below this exportation/definition you could then define other utility methods to accompany Users_Booking upon its importation. Something like the below code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// ... definition of Users_Booking_Schema ...

const Users_Booking = module.exports = mongoose.model('Users_Booking', Users_Booking_Schema);

module.exports.generateUniqueReservationNumber() {
    // generate a unique booking id
    return booking_uid;
}

// ... any other utility functions ...
```

No need to mess with the prototype. With the Users_Booking being its own collection reference, you could just append functionality right below its definition/exportation in the very same file. That way you can keep your code encapsulated and you will not need to mess with the prototype.

So yes, appending to the prototype may work *(testing around is always recommended)*. I believe that the method described above will better suit your program's needs.